# Error while trying to retrieve dwm sources

Tags: debian, software-installation, dwm

I am trying to build `dwm` from source.

Grabbing the source doesn't work:

```
(28) $ apt-get source dwm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

This is my `sources.list` file:

```
## CRUNCHBANG
## Compatible with Debian Wheezy, but use at your own risk.
deb http://packages.crunchbang.org/waldorf waldorf main
deb-src http://packages.crunchbang.org/waldorf waldorf main

## DEBIAN
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free

## DEBIAN SECURITY
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
```

What URL(s) should I put in my `sources.list` to get `apt-get source dwm` to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget to run `apt-get update` after changing your `sources.list`.